# How does page refresh work?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, refresh

I've been looking on Stackoverflow to find a way to reload a page in the same way F5 does. I mean I have the following problem:

I have a php page containing a form (let's say data.php) and a table containing a DB data. Form calls another php page to execute an action (action.php) via post method. Action.php is called and my DB is updated. Now I want to go back in data.php and I want table to be updated reading changes in my DB.

What I did was trying in action.php the following:

1. Header('Location: data.php'): this didnt work because it sent me to data.php but I couldn't see any change in the table before refreshing the page via F5, I found it is due to the fact php is a server-side language so it can't act on your browser and tell it to reload the page, is that correct?
2. Header('Location: data.php?u=reload'): then in data.php a control on $_GET['u'], if that variable equal to reload I made data.php set header data.php and then call a jscript location.reload. Again I hadn't any change in the table.

Now I would like data.php table to be automatically refreshed after DB updates so to make user able to immediately see changes he introduced without the need of manually reload the page, how can I do?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

What it actually happens is the following: I have a folder where images are stored in the form imgID.EXT and a DB where images data is stored in the form ID,EXT,TEXT. Data.php loads a list of images ordered by ID with their own text and has buttons to modify the list (something like every image has moveup button, movedown button, delete button). When I call moveup I go to action.php and it changes ID of image moving it up in the list and changing the name in the image folder, then go back to data.php.

I have that after redirecting I see images in the same position as before but for example TEXT of image#5 correctly swap with TEXT of image#4. When I refresh using F5 (or browser button to reload the page) image#5 swaps with image#4 and everything is ok. I would like anything to swap without the need of using F5 but just can't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Use AJAX to post the values of the form, then use js to add the result to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably mySQL isn't finished inserting/updating your row in the database before your user loads the data.php. I have had this once and solved is with a sleep(1) before my header redirect.

This isn't the best solution but it solves the problem. Better 'd be to use some javascript to process the form or redirect the user after showing a success notification.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just noticed indid that when I go back to data.php the table has properly read the SQL changes. What the page hasn't read is the change in images URL.

I better explain:
I have a folder where uploaded images are saved in the form imgID.EXT where ID and EXT are read in a DB table called img containg the fields ID,EXT and TEXT.

Data.php loads images from the folder and associate to any image its own TEXT field. When I go back from Action to Data I can see changes in TEXT but I have to refresh in order to get images reordered, I write this better in main post.

Comment: This is most likely a cache problem. The old image will still be in your browser cache. When you refresh it will reload this image. Changing the file name after an update would solve this.

Comment: Hm understood, so it depends on cache. I'll try to solve in a different way because actually changing the name of file would be a problem because page layout relies on image names.

Comment: I actually solved introducing a script which makes the page reloading once (using location.reload()) after you have been redirected to it. Don't know if it is the best solution but it is working. Thanks everyone!